# Add value in dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe

I am new to StackOverflow

This is my second time asking a similar question because the first one was not clear and was duplicate. By the way, I am new and trying to learn web scraping.

This is what I have done so far:

I have a list of string where the first index is column name having next index as it's value. Similarly, the third index is the column name but with the different name having the fourth index is the value.

I wanted to put all this list into the data frame having column name 'i' having the value 'i_next'

```
text=my_detail[0].split('\n')
#for example text=['a','2','b','3',c,'4'] <is a list not dataframe>
#some of the string in text is not require
#example the text can be ['a','2','f','b','3','c','4']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

for i,nexti in zip(text,text[1:]):

    if i in df.columns:
        #store df at column name i having value nexti  
'''
The expected answer is
a b c
2 3 4
'''
```

In case this question again got any problem or duplicate you can comment and I will delete it.

Thank you for your consideration,

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(text[::2],text[1::2])),index=[0])` ..?

Comment: sorry for the unclear statement i am manully giving columns name to dataframe as   i would like to add only specific name because some the string in text is not require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor, get values for values by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([text[1::2]], columns=text[::2])
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  2  3  4
```

EDIT:

Solution in loop - idea is create list of dictionaries and pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L= [['a\n2','b\n3','c\n4'], ['a\n20','b\n30','c\n40']]

final = []
for x in L:
    inner = {}
    for y in x:
        text = y.split('\n')
        for a, b in zip(text[::2],text[1::2]):
            inner[a] = b
    final.append(inner)

print (final)
[{'a': '2', 'b': '3', 'c': '4'}, {'a': '20', 'b': '30', 'c': '40'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(final)
print (df)

    a   b   c
0   2   3   4
1  20  30  40
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jezrael. but my text also has unused string so i want  to add it's value by matching the string with the column name of data frame.